# Changing the visibility of a frozen object?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visibility, freezable

I'm trying to optimize my WPF/VB.net program, and I'm considering freezing some objects. However, while I know that an object that is animated in any way cannot be frozen, I need to know...can you change the visibility of a frozen object?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freezing a `Freezable` object conceptually makes it immutable so an attempt to write to any writable properties should throw an exception, including `Visibility`.  You can however implicitly affect a `Freezable` object's state by containing it in a non-freezable object.  For example, you can use a `Grid` or any other `Panel` as a wrapper and toggle the `Visibility` of the container and it will affect the seemingly immutable frozen object indirectly.  That being said, freezing doesn't really buy you very much efficiency-wise unless you are making quite a lot of copies of the object.